# retain window configuration for nav-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I often have my emacs frame split vertically so that I have R or Python running in the lower window and a script open in the upper window. When I invoke `nav-mode`, this configuration is lost. I wonder if there is an easy fix to have `nav-mode` retain this vertical-split configuration when it opens its own window to the left.

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Nav ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - there is not. Nav always kills all open windows, but the current one - this was design decision. And there is no way to alter it, other than altering the nav code itself(which is not that hard).

Answer (score 0):

A new version of Nav is available that allows what you are asking for. It no longer does anything to the windows.

Comment: Which version of Nav allows you to do this?